# How does the computer implement callbacks?

Tags: linux

I already know the general usage of callback. First,I register a "callback function",when some event occur,this function will be triggered(be executed). What confuses me is how do I know if the event is occur? The solution I can get is polling.Is there a better way to check whether the event occur in less than the O(n) time ?

All right,Maybe the above question is too abstract.A more realistic description is does epoll_wait() avoid using O(n) time to check whether the ready file descriptor?

If so, how did it do it? Is there a callback mechanism that is different from polling essentially?

Comment: Any code for example? Did you mean function pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In a typical event-driven interface, a callback function does not poll to wait on an event. It is simply made known to the event manager. In a simple implementation, an object will have a set of events associated with it, and each of this object's events will have a function pointer (or a list thereof) that will be called when that event is processed.